# Kinect Hand Gestures

Tags: kinect, gesture

I have been working with Kinect gestures for a while now and so far the tools that are available to create gestures are only limited to track entire body movements for instance swiping your arm to left and right. The JOINT TYPES available in the original Kinect SDK involves elbows, wrists, hands, shoulders etc but doesn’t include minor details like index finger, thumb, and middle finger. I am mentioning al this because I am trying to create gestures involving only hand movements (like victory sign, thumb up/down). Can anyone guide me though this? Is there a blog or website where codes for hand movements are written?

Comment: Please check Google, Bing or other favorite search engine.  There are multiple projects that demonstrate using the Kinect for recognizing hand gestures, using different APIs to accomplish this.  The depth cameras in the Kinect can provide some useful information, but there is nothing particularly special about using a Kinect for hand tracking over previous methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing application with Kinect one year ago, and then it was very hard or nearly impossible to do that. Now Google shows me projects like [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Finger-Tracking-with-Kinect-SDK-and-the-Kinect-for-XBox-360-Device), be sure to check it out. If you generally want to focus on hands gestures, I really advise you to use  [LEAP Motion](https://www.leapmotion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

My friends at [SigmaRD](http://www.sigmard.com/) have developed something called the [SigmaNIL Framework](http://www.sigmanil.com/). You can [get it from the OpenNI website](http://www.openni.org/files/sigmanil-framework/#.UYzI_7X-HXI).

It offers "HandSegmentation", "HandSkeleton", "HandShape" and "HandGesture" modules which may cover your needs.

Also check out the rest of the [OpenNI Middleware and Libraries](http://www.openni.org/software/?cat_slug=file-cat1#.UYzKZLX-HXL) that you can download from their website. Some of them also work with the Microsoft SDK.